# Define attribute classes during readOGR

Tags: r, rgdal

Is there any possibility to declare the data type of the attribute columns when importing, for example, a ESRI Shapefile with the `readOGR` command?

For example, I would like to keep the leading zeros in my key column (`id_code`):

```
example<- readOGR(example.shp", example")
str(example@data) 
#'data.frame': 7149 obs. of  22 variables:
# $ id_code: num  101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 ...
```

The result should something be like this:

```
str(example@data) 
#'data.frame': 7149 obs. of  22 variables:
# $ id_code: char  "0101" "0102" "0103" "0104" "0105" "0106"...
```

I am looking for something similar as `colClasses` in the `read.csv()` function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare the data type when importing by specifying the `encoding`, `ogrDrivers` and `use_iconv` options in `readOGR`.

Please see `?readOGR`.

From the documentation for the `encoding` option:

> default NULL, if set to a character string, and the driver is **“ESRI
>   Shapefile”**, and use_iconv is FALSE, it is passed to the CPL Option
>   “SHAPE_ENCODING” immediately before reading the DBF of a shapefile. If
>   use_iconv is TRUE, and encoding is not NULL, it will be used to
>   convert input strings from the given value to the native encoding for
>   the system/platform.

You may also want to look into `ogrInfo`.

Comment: I had read `?readOGR`, but still could not figure out to do it correctly. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/OGR_shape_encoding.pdf) did not help either. 
Could you give an example?